# Where to find AVAYA Stationlink SDK Doc?

Tags: avaya

Where should i get AVAYA statiinlink SDK reference. I tried to find it but no luck?

Can anybody gives me some links for that?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Avaya DevConnect site has opened up their SDK's and programming environment to any developer now.

Simply sign up at : http://www.devconnectprogram.com/

You can then access all the SDK's for Avaya telephony you want.

Enjoy!